# string.format conundrum

Tags: c#

for me where the following simple string.format() doesn't work !!

```
return string.format(Resources.ABCSTRING, fieldName, fieldType);
```

where Resouces.ABCSTRING is

```
    {1} _{0};
    internal {1} {0}
    {
        get { return _{0}; }
        set
        {
            _{0} = value;
            UpdateRowValue(myObj, "{0}", value);
        }

    }
    internal void SetNull{0}()
    {
        UpdateRowValue(myObj, "{0}", DBNull.Value);
    }
```

It's obviously something basic but i don't see it !! any help ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to escape the standalone braces.

You need to change it to

```
{1} _{0};
internal {1} {0}
{{
    get {{ return _{0}; }}
    set
    {{
        _{0} = value;
        UpdateRowValue(myObj, "{0}", value);
    }}

}}
internal void SetNull{0}()
{{
    UpdateRowValue(myObj, "{0}", DBNull.Value);
}}
```